# Extended Events, sp_reset_connection and sql_text

Tags: sql-server

I have extended event sessions running on 3 different servers. I am looking for long running or excessively called stored procedures and in-line queries (ORMs, primarily nHibernate).

The output for rpc_completed event_name shows 'sp_reset_connection' for object_type and statement_text. But, it also has a query captured in sql_text.

Does Extended Events capture the 2 executions --sp_reset_connection and the query -- as a single event? Should I view the duration value to be for the combined time for sp_reset_connection plus the query in sql_text or statement_text? Or, is it capturing sp_reset_connection and simply showing the query that triggered sp_reset_connection?

I was expecting the sp_reset_connection and the queries to be separate events.

CLARIFICATION:
Why does Extended Events return a conflict between fields?

```
1. object_name = 'sp_reset_connection'
2. statement = 'exec sp_reset_connection'
3. sql_text = a query (ex: '(@p0 int)SELECT specificat0_.ScenarioId ...')
```

Why is sql_text different?  In a typical Extended Events row (XML), the 3 fields are in agreement as to what has been executed. Which leaves me with the question of "What was executed?".  Should the duration field value be assigned to sp_reset_connection? Or the in-line sql found in sql_text? Or both?

I understand what sp_reset_connection is and how it works.  What I do not understand is how Extended Events is reporting it.  Profiler did not have ambiguity when reporting sp_reset_connection.

My conclusion is that Extended Events is returning the results for sp_reset_connection.  However, that is a conclusion based on what I observe -- i.e a guess. I need something more concrete:  even if only someone else that reached the same conclusion.

This article indicates that I can ignore sql_text.

https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/understanding-the-sql_text-action-in-extended-events/

Thank you for your help.

Comment: [dup on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70585562/sql-server-extended-events-and-sp-reset-connection)

Comment: You shouldn't care at all about `sp_reset_connection`, it's designed to reset the connection settings with connection pooling. It's called specially by a specific bit in a TDS packet, it takes up one eighth of a byte and a tiny amount of time to execute. See also https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/bobb/sql-server-and-pooled-vs-non-pooled-connections/ et al

Comment: @Charlieface I agree.  sp_reset_connection should not be an issue. Problem is which do I believe?  object_name, statement or sql_text?   sql_text contains a query.   object_name = sp_reset_connection.  statement = exec sp_reset_connection.   duration = 5.   My conclusion is that object_name = sp_reset_connection is the driver.  But, that is just my opinion.

Comment: I think `statement` is just a representation of what an RPC call would *look* like if executed in T-SQL (Profiler shows the same by the way). An RPC call doesn't do that, it uses a more specialized TDS format. And `sp_reset_connection` isn't really an RPC call either, as mentioned. So I'm unclear what you are trying to find out: you cannot call `sp_reset_connection` from code, so it *must* be the `RESETCONNECTION` bit being set. Ergo, why do you care at all about this? It's simply an observational artefact and shouldn't affect your life

Comment: @Charlieface Extended Events returns conflicting information.  I want to determine which is correct.  I can guess, reasonably conclude, or whatever.  But, that is still a guess. I have spent hours searching Extended Events articles and cannot determine why a single event in Extended Events returns a query in the sql_text field, but claims that the statement = exec sp_reset_connection.   What was executed?  The query in sql_text? Or the one in statement? How do I aggregate number of executions (or duration) if I cannot explicitly determine what was excecuted?

Comment: Noting was executed, at least nothing that can be seen as "normal SQL or procedure call". A signal was sent over the TDS protocol instructing SQL Server to clean up this connection. XE represents this as sp_reset_connection, even though there's no procedure with that name. Or are you saying that you have something different in there like a "real" query or procedure? If so, please add details/example to your initial post and comment here. My guess in that case is that the client submitted a query or "real" proc call, and the TDS package *also* has the "reset" bit on.

Comment: Here you can categorically see that `sp_reset_connection` cannot be executed in T-SQL https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8164fde108523ef151d2db3604bf74ce. As mentioned, for RPC calls the `statement` is just a textual representation of what it *might* look like if executed in T-SQL (because an RPC call isn't T-SQL *either*). Do you have any instance of `sp_reset_connection` that *don't* look like that? And if you are trying to measure how long it takes to reset the connection, perhaps you should run it in a loop or something, although I really don't think you should worry about it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sys.sp\_reset\_connection. Why theres a lot of them ?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102431/sys-sp-reset-connection-why-theres-a-lot-of-them)

Comment: @Charlieface  Thank you.  No, it does not answer my question.  I understand what sp_reset_connection is.  I do not understand how Extended Event is reporting it.  Why is there a conflict between statement and sql_text.  Typically the XML shows agreement between object_name, statement and sql_text.    Why is there a conflict of information between sql_text and the other fields?  Which one is correct?

Comment: I updated the original question and title. Hopefully clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will preface this by saying that `sp_reset_connection` is not something you normally need to worry about. It is not executed as a full RPC call, it's just a single bit flag in a TDS packet, and executes very quickly.

Furthermore, XEvents and Profiler present it, as well as normal RPC stored procedure calls, in the form `exec SomeProc @param1...`, but that is not what is actually executing. It is merely a *textual representation* of what such a call *might* look like if executed as a T-SQL batch. RPC calls instead use a specific TDS mechanism, which passes just `SomeProc`, and separately passes the parameters.

Given that, and judging from my own testing, I think what is going on here is that XEvents is showing each procedure call, as well as a separate call to `sp_reset_connection`, even though they are from the same RPC call.

So for an ad-hoc batch with parameters, you get `sql_text = '(@param1 ...)SELECT whatever'`, because that is the call that has triggered `sp_reset_connection` (although in testing I don't get this detail). And as mentioned in [your linked article](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/understanding-the-sql_text-action-in-extended-events/), this value should really be called `input_buffer` which is what it really represents.

Meanwhile, `statement = 'exec sp_reset_connection'` because that is what the equivalent T-SQL *might* look like ([you can't actually call it directly in T-SQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8164fde108523ef151d2db3604bf74ce), although you can with a normal RPC call eg via SqlClient).

And the *actual* object being called is stored in `object_name = 'sp_reset_connection'`. This is what you should focus on if you want to know if a stored procedure was called, or if `sp_executesql` was called (for ad-hoc). And you should add a filter to your XEvent to remove `sp_reset_connection`

```sql
....
  ADD EVENT sqlserver.rpc_completed(
    ACTION(sqlserver.sql_text)
    WHERE (object_name <> 'sp_reset_connection')
  )
```

---

To prove my point that there *are* two events being triggered, and that *both* show the input batch in `sql_text`, see the following screenshots of a parameterized ad-hoc batch sent from .Net's SqlClient

[image: reset event]

and this one:

[image: main event]

Comment: Thank you!!  That was the goal!

Comment: Thank you again.  I really appreciate the effort you made for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Charlieface is indeed correct in that the trace engine show two events and not one. I'll leave this for clarity and in case others read this thread.[/EDIT]

Charlieface's answer suggests that you see *two* events in the trace for what is actual one event in the engine. I.e., the client sends a query to SQL Server and the TDS package also has the "reset connection" bit turned on.

The way I read your updated question text, it seems that you have *one* event in the trace, not two events. I conclude this from your CLARIFICATION where you say you have three fields from what I assume is one (1) event:

> CLARIFICATION: Why does Extended Events return a conflict between
> fields?
>
> 1. object_name = 'sp_reset_connection'
> 2. statement = 'exec sp_reset_connection'
> 3. sql_text = a query (ex: '(@p0 int)SELECT specificat0_.ScenarioId ...')

So, The first two fields (1 and 2) represents the "clean up connection" bit in the TDS package. And the third field represent the actual query that was submitted (in that same package, represented as one event).

Say that you add the suggested filter to your trace:

```
WHERE (object_name <> 'sp_reset_connection')
```

You now miss the actual SQL query that the client submitted, which was the whole reason for running the trace in the first place!

Comment: Your answer is exactly what prompted me to ask my question.  So, I up voted it. However, as best as I can tell it is a single event:  exec sp_reset_connection.  In addition to @charlieface's comment, I found the following:  1) the link I provided in the CLARIFICATION section of my Question;  2) my understanding of xevents rpc completed:  one row - one event and 3)  typical 5 microsecond duration for the events.  The query text found in sql_text would take 50 to 500 milliseconds to execute (nHibernate sql). For now, I conclude that one row = exec sp_reset_connection.  Thank you for your reply.

Comment: I indeed see two separate events in the XEvent trace, with the *same* `sql_text` but one has `object_name = 'sp_reset_connection'` will post a screenshot soon

Comment: See new screenshots in my answer showing two separate events

Comment: Thanks @Charlieface, that makes it perfectly clear! So there's really only one TDS package containing both the reset bit as well as a query, but XE show this as two events. IMO, XE is misleading in doing that, considering there's a field (action?) for the reset option available, so generating only one event should be less confusing. I'll leave my answer with some edits in case future readers might have the same line of thoughts...

Comment: I think the point is that two procedures are being called via RPC, using the same input buffer. If you think of `sql_text` as representing the input buffer *not* the currently executing SQL, then it makes more sense

Comment: I see your point, but IMO sp_reset_connection isn't really a proc anyhow, it is just represented as such for us mere mortals. :-) One can discuss which is the right way, but it is the way it is. The important thing is that we (you) have clarified how it work!

Comment: It's hard to say *what* it is. It's certainly not a normal `CREATE PROCEDURE`, it has no SQL definition. Equally there are many other system procedures with no definition. It *can* be called via a normal RPC, so in that respect it acts as a normal proc, but it cannot be called via a T-SQL ad-hoc batch. One assumes it has been written in highly performant C++, but I'm not familiar enough with the engineering